# using jquery to select an anchor to display a text area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 <a class='reply' href='' id='<?php echo rand(9999,999999).$ro['comment_user_id'];?>'>Reply</a>
 echo "<form id='post' ' action='' style='dispay:none'  id='<?php echo rand(9999,999999).$ro['comment_user_id'];?>'>";
    echo"<ul>";
            echo"<li><b>Reply:</b></li>";
            echo"<li><textarea   name='comment_content' /></textarea></li>";
            echo"<li><input type='submit' value='Add Comment' /></li>";
            echo"</ul>";
            echo"</form>";
         <script>               
 $(document).ready(function(){          
    $('.reply').click(function() {                  
var anchor=document.getElementById(this.id);                       
      var id=anchor.getAttribute('id');             
     $('#'+id).show();          
     return false;          
     });   
     });            
 </script>
```

I  want to dispay a form for each anchor element with unique Id when clicked but is not working.Pls help

Comment: 1. `.show()` is jquery function not javascript, 
2. you have not closed php tag before script.

Answer (score 1):

You had `echo rand(9999,999999)` for each of the ids, making the `.reply` and the form likely to have different ids.
Also, `<form id='post' ' action='' style='dispay:none'  id='<?php echo rand(9999,999999).$ro['comment_user_id'];?>'>` has its `id` set twice and also has an extra `'` after the first id.
An html `id` cannot start with a number, so I gave them the prefixes `reply-` and `form-`.

```
<?php
$randID = rand(9999,999999);
?>
<a class='reply' href='' id='reply-<?php echo $randID . $ro["comment_user_id"]; ?>'>Reply</a>
<?php
    echo "<form type='post' action='' style='dispay:none' id='form-" . $randID . $ro['comment_user_id'] . "'>";
    echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li><b>Reply:</b></li>";
            echo "<li><textarea   name='comment_content' /></textarea></li>";
            echo "<li><input type='submit' value='Add Comment' /></li>";
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</form>";
?>
 <script>               
 $(document).ready(function(){          
    $('.reply').click(function() {  
         var id = this.id.substr(6);                
         $('form#form-' + id).show();
         return false;          
     });   
 });            
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ Villa7, your awesome. Catch up with you next time

Comment: Thanks so much @ Villa7, your awesome.  It displayed the form! TO hide that anchor when it displays the form I used $('a#reply-'+id).hide(); but itz its still showing. Any help pls

Comment: @Benmatics if you want to hide the clicked `.reply` you could use `$(this).hide()`

Comment: Thanks bro @Villa

Comment: <?php $randID=rand(9999,999999);?>
 <a class='reply' href='' id='reply-<?php echo $randID.$ro['comment_user_id'];?> '>Reply</a>
<?php echo "<div  style='display:none' id='form-".$randID.$ro['comment_user_id']."' >"; echo"<ul>"; echo"<li><input id='comment_id' type='hidden' value='".$ro['comment_id']."'></li>";
 echo"<li><input id='comment_topic_id' type='hidden' value='".$ro['comment_topic_id']."'></li>";
 echo"<li><textarea  id='rep-".$randID.$ro['comment_user_id']."'></textarea></li>";
 echo"<li><button  class='send_reply'>Send Reply</button></li>";
 echo"</ul>";
 echo"</div>";?>

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.send_reply').on('click',function() {
 var id=this.id.substr(4);
 var comment = $('textarea#rep-'+id).val();
 var com_id=document.getElementById('comment_id').value;
 var com_topic_id = document.getElementById('comment_topic_id').value;
$.post('user_send_reply.php',{reply_content:comment,reply_comment_id:com_id,reply_topic_id:com_topic_id}).done(function(data){
 $('#center_page').html(data);
  });
   });
  });
?> pls help jquery code 4 d above

Comment: how do i select  comment id for each div in the loop? i succeeded in selecting textarea for each div. It refuse to enter the comment box

Comment: There _should_ only be one of each `id` on the page at once, so for your 2 `<input>`s, change them so that their `id`s also have the unique `$randID.$ro[' comment_user_id ']` suffix. That way you can then access them in the same way as the `textarea`: `$('#comment_id-' + id).val()` and $('#comment_topic_id-'+id).val()`

Comment: Thanks @Villa7 u have really helped me in dis project i stil have two major problems: my code <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('.topics').click(function() { var anchor=document.getElementById(this.id); var url=anchor.getAttribute('href'); $('#center_page').html(url);return false; }); }); </script>. This is the anchor. <a class='topics' id="<?php echo $row['topic_id'];?>" href=" <?php include 'links.php';?>" ><?php echo $row['topic_subject'];?></a> that anchor href is not neat cos it contains a full page, how can i display links.php without including it in href attribute

Comment: @benmatics Look into using [`$().load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) in the click listener of `.topics`. Instead of storing the entire page html in the href of the anchor, instead store the path to the page and use `.load()` to place it in `#center_page`.

Comment: Also every user in my site has a page accesses by link:www.mysitename.com/page_name  people who are not logged in can visit the page and read articles and adverts added but can comment only wen they login.  everything works well but if you login and click on each page through that anchor,it will still be showing your own page. I want it to displace the login page and show the clicked page and still retain the "session user id" which is need to coment n reply

Comment: look at the anchor that displays every user page inside a loop from database<p style='margin:0;padding:0;font-style:italic;'>Page name:</p><a href='cog_user_home.php?page_name=<?php echo $user_fname['page_name'];?>' >

Comment: <?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  $res=mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM page_comments WHERE comment_topic_id='.$row['topic_id'].'')  or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));  ?>
   <li><a class="sample" id="<?php echo $row['topic_id'];?>" href="links.php"><?php echo $row['topic_subject'];?></a></li>
    <?php
   }
   ?>  I get error of undefined variable row in links.php when i use .load()<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sample').on('click',function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    var url=this.href;
   $("#center_page").load(url); 
     });
 })
</script>

Comment: Thanks I have been able to figure out what I did using the session variable you sugested but am stil having problem with $("#center_page").load(url). Is there any way i can pass variable from current page to the page loaded which need those variables

Comment: @benmatics If the page you are loading is rendered with php you could pass the variables through `load()` in the query string of the url: `.load('links.php?foo=var&foo2=var2')`. Then have `links.php` render based off of the `$_GET['foo']` variables.